# Vala yield not returning

Tags: asynchronous, gtk, yield, glib, vala

I'm having trouble writing an async function in Vala.
I understand that the function's callback has to get registered somewhere in order for execution to continue after the yield statements, so I add it to the GLib mainloop to be called periodically using `Idle.add`. Here is my dummy code:

```
async void loop_func()
{
    var id = Idle.add(loop_func.callback);
    message("Added idle %u",id);

    yield;
    message("yielded successfully 1");

    yield;
    message("yielded successfully 2");

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        message("%d",i);
        yield;
    }

    message("finished");
}

int main()
{
    var loop = new GLib.MainLoop();
    loop_func.begin(() => {loop.quit();});
    loop.run();
    return 0;
}
```

Despite this, the code after the 2nd yield statement never gets executed.
This can be seen from the output:

```
$ ./async   
** Message: 20:07:24.932: async.vala:4: Added idle 1
** Message: 20:07:24.932: async.vala:7: yielded successfully 1
```

And then it hangs.
What am I missing here?

Comment: It's not clear to me what is supposed to happen when an async function has multiple `yield;` statements. Did you get this example from somewhere that might provide more context?

Comment: I'd like to do some expensive operations in the for loop, but yield control back to the CPU after every iteration to stop the thread from hanging. Every time I yield after an iteration of the loop, I'd like execution to continue from there whenever the CPU is free again.  
  
I've found the way to do this now; thanks for your help!

Comment: The purpose of the `yield` is to arrange an asynchronous callback, so when the time consuming operation is finished in a separate function then the flow returns to the yield, GIO has lots of async functions, e.g. `yield file.mount_mountable (MountMountFlags.NONE);`

Comment: Yes, there are plenty of examples of async functions with multiple `yield some_other_async_function();` but I could find none with multiple `yield;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although GLib calls an idle function repeatedly until it tells it to stop (by returning `false`), the async function's `.callback` seems to quit repeating immediately after being called.

This can be overcome by adding the callback again every time before the yield statement:

```
async void loop_func()
{
    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        Idle.add(loop_func.callback);
        yield;
    }
}
```

An alternative (and possibly more effective) way to do this would be to ignore the value that the async function's callback returns:

```
async void loop_func()
{
    var id = Idle.add(() => {loop_func.callback(); return Source.CONTINUE;});

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        yield;
    }

    Source.remove(id);
}
```

Comment: `MainLoop` is an abstraction over `GMainContext`, which is GLib's event loop and can be created per thread or more, allowing for multiple event loops, if you are trying to add flow control to time consuming operations, but want to maintain a separate responsive thread, e.g. for user input, then may be take a look at https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/custom-gsource.c.html.en for inspiration